# What does "1 line adds whitespace errors" mean when applying a patch?

Tags: git, whitespace, patch, git-patch

I'm editing some markdown files of a cloned remote repository, and wanted to test creating and applying patches from one branch to another. However, every time I make any change at all, I get the following message during `git apply`:

```
0001-b.patch:16: trailing whitespace.
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
```

(This is happening on my Mac, and I don't know where the original code was created.)

What does the warning message mean, and do I need to care?

Comment: Related ("why?"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583406/why-does-git-care-about-trailing-whitespace-in-my-files

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You don't need to care.

The warning enacts a standard of cleanliness of text files in regard to whitespace, the kind of thing that many programmers tend to care about. As [the manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-apply.html) explains:

> What are considered whitespace errors is controlled
>   by core.whitespace configuration. By default, trailing whitespaces
>   (including lines that solely consist of whitespaces) and a space
>   character that is immediately followed by a tab character inside the
>   initial indent of the line are considered whitespace errors.
>
> By default, the command outputs warning messages but applies the patch.

So, the "error" means that the change introduces a trailing whitespace, a whitespace-only line, or a space that precedes a tab. Other than that fact, there is nothing erroneous about the change, and it will apply cleanly and correctly. In other words, if you don't care about the "incorrect" whitespace, feel free to ignore the warning or turn it off with `git config apply.whitespace nowarn`.

Comment: Thanks. The strange part is I'm quite positive the change doesn't introduce any new whitespace issues - I literally inserted a single word in the middle of a sentence..

Comment: Look at the commit with `git show` — if your git does colors, you will see the offending whitespace come up in angry red. Also, `git show --word-diff` will show you not only the line change, but insertions in the middle of the line, which should show whether the patch *really* only adds a word in the middle, or if it also adds a trailing whitespace.

Comment: You don't *need* to care. But you should. Trailing whitespace should be eradicated.

Comment: Except the OP adds no new trailing whitespace, only modifies what already exists.

Comment: I have seen this prop up in a similar situation when the line endings are Windows style CRLFs instead of Unix ones.

Comment: @Yarin If you add a word in the middle of a line, and the line already has trailing whitespace, that may trigger the warning.

Comment: The question is, when you see 5 of these merging branches, how do you know where these are? There is no filenames as far as I can tell. I could only find one by grepping, the rest I had no luck. But line numbers did not match.

Comment: I had success with `git config --global apply.whitespace nowarn`, but not with `git config core.whitespace nowarn`.

Comment: OK, so what if you *do* care? How do you find the errors?

Comment: @EdwardFalk `git diff` will show the errors in red.

Comment: True, but merge operations don't. They just display the ambiguous errors shown in the question.

Comment: @EdwardFalk This question is about the behavior of `git apply`. Can you be more specific about what you mean by "merge operations"?

Comment: ... and if you *do* care, it's easy to fix. Assuming you just committed those whitespace warned offenders: 1) identify the culprits using `git show` 2) `git add --patch` [fix just the whitespace errors, leave everything else alone] 3) `git commit --amend` 4) Run `git show` and achieve whitespace zen. Note that you could also fix them by backing out your staging, but there are times you may not want to do that. (Say, you're in the middle of another `git add --patch` session.)

Comment: @user4815162342, why is this the default setting though?

Comment: @Pacerier Good question. I think it's because trailing whitespace is almost always introduced accidentally and creates much problems with VCS when applying diffs and merging branches. git developers likely wanted their VCS to detect and correct the problem at the earliest opportunity, when reviewing the patch. But I don't have citations for any of this, so take it with a grain of salt. It could also be a personal preference by the git developers, some people are quite fussy about whitespace.

Answer (score 7):

One case when you could legitimately care is when you want to differentiate between "old" whitespase error (that you might want to keep for legacy reason) and "new" whitespace errors (that you want to avoid).

To that effect, Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will propose a more specific option for whitespace detection.

See [commits 0e383e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e383e185ae57a8ee6ba015a43749f6d34fe3c9a), [0ad782f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ad782f2406fa13f626653a001b5f01a9f3fa40f), and [d55ef3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d55ef3e04459a5f1a24f494b873d8590f2523add) [26 May 2015] by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 709cd91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/709cd912d4663af87903d3d278a3bab9d4d84153), 11 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `diff.c`: `--ws-error-highlight=<kind>` option
>
> Traditionally, we only cared about whitespace breakages introduced
>   in new lines.
>   **Some people want to paint whitespace breakages on old
>   lines, too.  When they see a whitespace breakage on a new line, they
>   can spot the same kind of whitespace breakage on the corresponding
>   old line and want to say "Ah, those breakages are there but they
>   were inherited from the original, so let's not touch them for now."**
>
> Introduce `--ws-error-highlight=<kind>` option, that lets them pass
>   a comma separated list of `old`, `new`, and `context` to specify
>   what lines to highlight whitespace errors on.

The [documentation now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b8767f791c15f119554c1466af60e4f2433ae971/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L282-L289):

```
--ws-error-highlight=<kind>
```

> Highlight whitespace errors on lines specified by `<kind>` in the color specified by `color.diff.whitespace`.
>   `<kind>` is a comma separated list of `old`, `new`, `context`.
>   When this option is not given, only whitespace errors in `new` lines are highlighted.
>
> E.g. `--ws-error-highlight=new,old` highlights whitespace errors on both deleted and added lines.
>   `all` can be used as a short-hand for `old,new,context`.

For instance, the old commit had one whitespace error (`bbb`), but you can focus on the new errors only (at the end of `still bbb` and `ccc`):

[image: old and new shitespace errors]

(test done after [`t/t4015-diff-whitespace.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b8767f791c15f119554c1466af60e4f2433ae971/t/t4015-diff-whitespace.sh#L872-L898))

---

With Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), the `diff-*` plumbing family of subcommands now pay attention to the `diff.wsErrorHighlight` configuration, which has been ignored before; this allows "`git add -p`" to also show the whitespace problems to the end user.

See [commit da80635](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da8063522f7f797cf722f28979aefbe2a508f800) (31 Jan 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit df04a31](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df04a316176d5ba44422c2c6b0cb1a9fc31901e5), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da8063522f7f797cf722f28979aefbe2a508f800): move diff.wsErrorHighlight to "basic" config
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> We parse diff.wsErrorHighlight in `git_diff_ui_config()`, meaning that it doesn't take effect for plumbing commands, only for porcelains like [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) itself.
>   This is mildly annoying as it means scripts like `add--interactive`, which produce a user-visible diff with color, **don't respect the option**.
>
> We could teach that script to parse the config and pass it along as `--ws-error-highlight` to the diff plumbing. But there's a simpler solution.
>
> It should be reasonably safe for plumbing to respect this option, as it only kicks in when color is otherwise enabled. And anybody parsing colorized output must already deal with the fact that `color.diff.*` may change the exact output they see; those options have been part of `git_diff_basic_config()` since its inception in [9a1805a872](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a1805a8726ee41f25be2e0f2d5f38f1150d38e4) (add a "basic" diff config callback, 2008-01-04, Git v1.5.4-rc3).
>
> So we can just move it to the "basic" config, which fixes `add--interactive`, along with any other script in the same boat, with a very low risk of hurting any plumbing users.

Answer (score 2):

The whitespace error with visual images is shown here.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Contributing-to-a-Project#Commit-Guidelines

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
git config apply.whitespace fix
```

before every commit use :

```
git add -up .
```

Answer (score -2):

Because line begining with `TAB` istead of `SPACE`. Go on patch file and replace `TAB` with `SPACE`. E.g. on vim on line + from patch file type x to remove space and not remove sign + and insert space (CTRL) on eqiv to original size.

Comment: -1 You really think git would complain about Linus style tab indentation? The only legit use of tab, if any, is precisely the beginning of the line.