# git rebase result

Tags: git, git-rebase

It was my first try to understanding how git rebase is working.
I was on new branch did a lot of changes and then I'd try `git rebase`, and in result I got next output:

```
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: new features done
/sandbox/.git/rebase-apply/patch:2825: trailing whitespace.
    var upl_div = document.getElementById('upload_form');
/sandbox/.git/rebase-apply/patch:2826: trailing whitespace.
    var crt_div = document.getElementById('create_form');
/sandbox/.git/rebase-apply/patch:2827: trailing whitespace.
    var appl_div = document.getElementById('create_letter');
warning: squelched 309 whitespace errors
warning: 314 lines add whitespace errors.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
<stdin>:2825: trailing whitespace.
    var upl_div = document.getElementById('upload_form');
<stdin>:2826: trailing whitespace.
    var crt_div = document.getElementById('create_form');
<stdin>:2827: trailing whitespace.
    var appl_div = document.getElementById('create_letter');
warning: squelched 310 whitespace errors
warning: 309 lines applied after fixing whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging lib/functions_common.inc
Auto-merging .htaccess
Applying: new features done
```

And i don't understand it was successfully made ? it was rebased or merged ? what was happend ? how I can see those warnings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a rebase, git will take a bunch of commits, and try to apply the change that each of those introduced in turn.  (In other words, it's like a series of uses of `git cherry-pick`.)  Each of those re-applications may use git's merge machinery to try to resolve any conflicts that might arise by re-applying a change onto a new parent.

So, yes, you have just done a rebase, but each step of the rebase may involve using git's code for doing a merge.

The "trailing whitespace" warnings are there to tell you that applying the change added some lines with whitespace at the end.  git is sensitive about this (apparently since [it can cause problems for patches sent by email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1583406/223092)) and will warn you about such whitespace in various situations.  The "squelched" errors are just saying that that rather than print out hundreds of such warnings, it's squelched them down to one line.

Comment: OK thanks, but based on output was it successfull ? or I should resolve some conflicts ? or it's just removed some whitespace in new or original files ?

Comment: It was successful.  You should be able to see that by using gitk and seeing that your branch is now based on the tip of master.

Comment: yep, thanks it is tru, but what does it means that warning ? should I do something to avoid it in next time ?

Comment: @user1016265: I've updated my answer to discuss the whitespace warnings - you shouldn't need to worry about them.