# How to show space and tabs with git-diff

Tags: git, git-diff

I have the following output with git-diff.

```
- // sort list based on value    
+ // sort list based on value
```

How can I easily see the number of removed tabs/spaces at the end of the line ?

Comment: I would rather tell git to report space/tabs with the `.gitconfig` option `[alias] df = diff --ignore-space-at-eol -b -w --ignore-blank-lines`. This is not an answer but possible workaround...

Comment: @coin That does not help, it get rid of the spaces and tabs entirely and is no longer visible in the diff :-(

Comment: `git diff --ws-error-highlight=all` can also be useful (with Git 2.5+, Q2 2015). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30803980/6309)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Note: Git 2.5+ (Q2 2015) will propose a more specific option for whitespace detection.

See [commits 0e383e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e383e185ae57a8ee6ba015a43749f6d34fe3c9a), [0ad782f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ad782f2406fa13f626653a001b5f01a9f3fa40f), and [d55ef3e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d55ef3e04459a5f1a24f494b873d8590f2523add) [26 May 2015] by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 709cd91](https://github.com/git/git/commit/709cd912d4663af87903d3d278a3bab9d4d84153), 11 Jun 2015)</sup>

> ### `diff.c`: `--ws-error-highlight=<kind>` option
>
> Traditionally, we only cared about whitespace breakages introduced
>   in new lines.
>   **Some people want to paint whitespace breakages on old
>   lines, too.  When they see a whitespace breakage on a new line, they
>   can spot the same kind of whitespace breakage on the corresponding
>   old line and want to say "Ah, those breakages are there but they
>   were inherited from the original, so let's not touch them for now."**
>
> Introduce `--ws-error-highlight=<kind>` option, that lets them pass
>   a comma separated list of `old`, `new`, and `context` to specify
>   what lines to highlight whitespace errors on.

The [documentation now includes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b8767f791c15f119554c1466af60e4f2433ae971/Documentation/diff-options.txt#L282-L289):

```
--ws-error-highlight=<kind>
```

> Highlight whitespace errors on lines specified by `<kind>` in the color specified by `color.diff.whitespace`.
>   `<kind>` is a comma separated list of `old`, `new`, `context`.
>   When this option is not given, only whitespace errors in `new` lines are highlighted.
>
> E.g. `--ws-error-highlight=new,old` highlights whitespace errors on both deleted and added lines.
>   `all` can be used as a short-hand for `old,new,context`.

For instance, the old commit had one whitespace error (`bbb`), but you can focus on the new errors only:

[image: old and new shitespace errors]

(test done after [`t/t4015-diff-whitespace.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b8767f791c15f119554c1466af60e4f2433ae971/t/t4015-diff-whitespace.sh#L872-L898))

---

Update Git 2.11+ (Q4 2016, a year and half later) :

```
git config diff.wsErrorHighlight [old,new,context]
```

`git diff/log --ws-error-highlight=<kind>` lacked the corresponding configuration variable to set it by default. That is added in Git 2.11.

See [commit 0b4b42e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b4b42e7fe1b507fb387c18d9a2748768359bf5d), [commit 077965f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/077965f84a580b7e1de7d60ed13656bec19cc2fb), [commit f3f5c7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3f5c7f5201ef71e62cea41a8b692cace2dcf579) (04 Oct 2016) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e5272d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5272d304af3528163cd5faa822f88086448ae57), 26 Oct 2016)</sup>

Comment: does the syntax `git config diff.wsErrorHighlight all` work with 2.11 as well?

Comment: @GrantHumphries I just tested it: yes it does (git version 2.11.0.windows.1)

Answer (score 23):

I can think of multiple options:

- Configure Git to use colors: `git config --global color.ui true`. Whitespace at the end of lines is now highlighted in red.
- Pipe the output of `git diff` through `cat`: `git diff | cat -A`. The `-A` flag tells `cat` to show non-printable characters (e.g. `^I` for tab).

Comment: The cat works but I'd prefer a git only solution with config. Setting the ui.config to true does not change anything to my output. I found that `git config color.diff.whitespace "blue reverse"` works for space but not for tabs (there's no `color.diff.tabs` config).

Comment: @Nico: woops, that was meant to be `color.ui`, not `ui.config` :)

Comment: On OS X (BSD?) the options are -v for displaying non-printing characters and -e shows a dollar sign at the end of each line.

Comment: I think you want `-t` for mac instead of `-v`.  This displays tabs as `^I`

Comment: The git config didn't seem to work when removing a trailing whitespace but the `cat` did, thanks!