# GitHub: How to ignore existing whitespaces when using git commit?

Tags: git, whitespace, commit

i modified a file "index.php", and i want to apply a push for the second time so i apply those commands:

> git add /path/to/index.php
>
> git commit --amend

but i have this result :

> /path/index.php:7: trailing whitespace.
>
> /path/index.php:52: trailing whitespace.
>
> /path/index.php:62: trailing whitespace.
>
> /path/index.php:81: trailing whitespace.

What i want is to **commit**  **ignoring** those **whitespaces** that are existing from the beginning in this file , i don't want to remove them.

Forcing the commit to ignore those **whitespaces**

I hope that any one have a solution for this issue.Thank you for your Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--no-verify` option.  Somebody did bother to write the custom code that's refusing things that look like what you're committing, you sure you want to this?

Comment: Thank you for your response , i just execute git commit --amend --no-verify and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can turn off the warnings/errors with git.

Have a look at this answer for reason.

[Why does git care about trailing whitespace in my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583406/why-does-git-care-about-trailing-whitespace-in-my-files)

Why do you not want to remove them?
Keeping them around can mess up future patches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to ignore whitespace in git, nor should there be - whitespace is data and git tracks changes to data, not code.

But what you can do, is suppress showing whitespace in your diffs with `git diff -w` (and with a github diff by adding the url parameter `?w=`)